# Applying Flexbox with both columns and rows layout

Tags: html, css, flexbox, multiple-columns

I wondered if you guys could help. It's been a few years since I sat down and created a website from scratch and I just want to do something
simple. I'm aware and have used breakpoints in the past but it looks like Flexbox may be an alternative way to do this(?). I haven't got my head around it yet and I'm finding it a bit tricky to apply it to my code.

In my layout I have two stacked rows: for the header and navigation links,
then two columns beneath for the main content and finally a row beneath these for the footer.

I'm including everything between body tags on my (work in progress) html page and the CSS below. Everything right now is in pixels. If you could give me any pointers on what I'm doing right and wrong (for instance, am I using too many containers, etc?) and how I'd be able to apply Flexbox to this I'd be most grateful.

```
body {
    background-color: #C4C4C4;
    font-family: 'Roboto', serif;
    /*font-size: 48px;*/
    line-height: 25px;
}

#page-container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 793px;
}

header {
    background: url("../images/big-banner.jpg");
    background-size: 793px 285px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 285px;
    /*height: 285px;*/
}

header h1 {
    padding: 70px 0 0 20px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 2.8em;
}

header p {
    padding: 25px 0 0 20px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 1.4em;
}


h2 {
    font-size: 1.4em;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}

h3 {
    font-size: 1em;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}


p {
    line-height: 1.7;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
}

ul {
    padding-left: 20px;
}

li {
    list-style-type: disc;
    line-height: 2em;
    padding-left: 5px;
}

nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #605A52;
}

nav li {
    float: left;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
}

nav li a {
    display: block;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1em;
    padding: 8px 15px 8px 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

nav li a:hover {
    color: #000000;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

strong { 
    font-weight: bold;
}

small {
    font-size: 0.9em;
}


section {

}

article {

}

.contact-box {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    padding: 15px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: -1px 3px 4px 0px rgba(102,102,102,0.73);
    -moz-box-shadow: -1px 3px 4px 0px rgba(102,102,102,0.73);
    box-shadow: -1px 3px 4px 0px rgba(102,102,102,0.73);
}

summary {

}


.content-container {
    width: 793px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
}

/* left col */
.left-col {
    padding: 40px 20px 60px 60px;
    width: 450px;
    float: left;
}

/* wull-width left col for contact page */
.full {
    width: 100%;
    padding-right: 40px;
}

/* right col */
.right-col {
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
    width: 243px;
    float: left;
    align-items: stretch;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 40px 20px 10px 20px;
    margin: 10px 0 0 0;
}

.zebra-1, .zebra-2 {
    text-align: justify;
    margin: 10px 0 10px 0;
}

.zebra-1 {
    background-color: #EDEDED;
}

.zebra-2 {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

.list-left, .list-right {
    text-align: left;
    float: left;
    width: 43%;
    padding-right: 5px;
}

footer {
    clear:both;
    background-color: #605A52;
    padding-left: 10px;
    color:#FFFFFF;
}

footer p {
    padding: 10px;
}


        <div id="page-container">

                <header>
                    <h1>Main title here</h1>
                    <p>Sub title</p>
                </header>

                <nav role="navigation">
                    <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>

                <div class="content-container zebra-1">
                    <section class="left-col" role="main">
                        <h2>Welcome</h2>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum
                        </p>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum
                        </p>
                    </section>

                    <div class="right-col zebra-1" role="complementary">
                        <aside><div class="contact-box">Contact info here</div></aside>
                    </div>
                </div>



                <div class="content-container zebra-2">
                    <section class="left-col" role="main">
                        <h2>Another header</h2>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum
                        </p>
                    </section>
                    <div class="right-col zebra-2" role="complementary">
                        <p>More stuff here</p>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <footer>
                    <p>
                    <small>Copyright info</small>
                    </p>
                </footer>

        </div>
```

Comment: This question is too broad and asks for opinions. Please narrow the question down to a specific programming-related problem. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

This might help you a little. You don't need to specify the width of the left and right col, nor float when you are using flex.

Try doing this and you will get the idea of how flex works.....

First I added the proper flex declarations for the other browsers:

```
.content-container {
    width: 793px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;

        display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-flow: wrap;
    -webkit-flex-flow: wrap;
    flex-flow: wrap;
}
```

Second, changed your left and right col:

```
/* left col */
.left-col {
    padding: 40px 20px 60px 60px;

        flex: 0 0 25%;
    -webkit-flex: 0 0 25%;
    -ms-flex: 0 0 25%;
}

/* right col */
.right-col {
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
    align-items: stretch;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 40px 20px 10px 20px;
    margin: 10px 0 0 0;

        flex: 0 0 25%;
    -webkit-flex: 0 0 25%;
    -ms-flex: 0 0 25%;
}
```

Try changing the % and you will get the idea!